# MSCD certification for sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, certification

I don't know if here is the right place to ask this question, so excuse me if it's not.

I want to take the SharePoint 2013 certification for developing applications (70-488)

I want know how much time it can take to learn SharePoint and prepare for the exam (I never worked with SharePoint , i'm just ASP.NET developer).

I know that it depends on how fast I learn, what you think for ordinary person ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an MSDN Premium subscription, you will be able to set up a development environment using VMs and you should also be able to sign up for a 1 year free Office 365 developer account. In addition to the Core Solutions jumpstart that Amal linked to there is also the one for the [Advanced Solutions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developing-SharePoint-Server-Advanced-Solutions) as well. You also should absolutely get a [PluralSight subscription](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses) as that was what helped me the most in my studies.

I wrote up a few blog posts on the [70-488](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/4/5/my-experience-with-the-70-488-exam-developing-sharepoint-core-solutions) and [70-489](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/3/1/my-experience-with-the-70-489-developing-advanced-solutions-exam).

I also compiled some resources on the exam topics.

[MCSD Exam 70-488 Resources - Implementing SharePoint Solutions](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/3/29/mcsd-exam-70-498-resources-implementing-sharepoint-solutions)
[MCSD Exam 70-488 Resources - Implement Authorization and Authentication (10-15 percent)](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/3/15/mcsd-exam-70-498-resources-implement-authorization-and-authentication-10-15-percent)
[MCSD Exam 70-488 Resources - Plan and Design SharePoint Sites](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/3/10/mcsd-exam-70-498-resources-plan-and-design-sharepoint-sites)
My [OneNote notes](https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=ED3A7F585AEB6F1B!4764&app=OneNote) which are not very complete.

And I compiled [a list of a few resources](http://www.robertkaucher.com/tech/2014/2/16/advancing-my-skills-as-a-sharepoint-and-web-developer) on the other exams that are required but are not specifically SharePoint.

As for the core question: Since you already have a professional background, I would give it 90 days per exam minimum. If MS is offering it, definitely take advantage of their second shot program. You might need to send an email to MS learning or something.