# Learning Sharepoint 2013 to ultimately get a MCSD

Tags: learning, training

I am looking for a way to learn the necessary knowledge in order to ultimately achieve an MCSD Sharepoint certification.

I have found the required tests on the Microsoft website: 70-486, 70-480, 70-488 and 70-489.

For test 70-486 Pluralsight has laid out a nice roadmap to train for the exam here:
http://blog.pluralsight.com/asp-net-mvc-microsoft-exam-70-486

And another for 70-480:
http://blog.pluralsight.com/learning-path-programming-in-html5-with-javascript-and-css3-microsoft-exam-70-480

The good news is that aside from Azure, I can already pass these tests with minimal study since I deal with this stuff on a daily basis.

The difficulty comes with Sharepoint - which I know very very little about. And I can't find a training path recommended by Pluralsight for the remaining two tests - 70-488 and 70-489.

I know that Pluralsight does have a number of Sharepoint training videos, but does anyone know of a good training path to utilize that would start with the basics, and then everything I need to know for these tests and, of course, to be a proficient Sharepoint developer?

If not Pluralsight, do you have any other recommendations? My only limitation is that it not be straight book-based learning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have another option to go for Instructor-led training for both exam.

[20488B: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions (five days)](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/course.aspx?ID=20488B)

[20489B: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions (five days)](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/course.aspx?ID=20489b)

also check this:

https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-488.aspx

https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-489.aspx

Comment: This prerequisite:
A basic working knowledge of SharePoint solution development, either in SharePoint 2013 or in earlier versions of SharePoint. 

I don't know much about SharePoint.  Could this be an obstacle?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two series of videos from Cloud9:

[Developing SharePoint 2013 Core Solutions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developing-SharePoint-2013-Core-Solutions)
[Developing SharePoint Server Advanced Solutions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developing-SharePoint-Server-Advanced-Solutions)

I would supplement these with two books:

- "Microsoft SharePoint 2013 App Development" by Ted Pattison and Scot Hillier
- "Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Developer Reference" by Paolo Pialorsi

A similar question was asked not too long ago, where you can find further resources:

[MSCD certification for sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126429/mscd-certification-for-sharepoint)